# getting field from object nested inside array with mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi I have array field in my document like here:

```
{
    otherFields....,
    "SlsIvcDtls": [
        {
            "_t": [
                "LocalSalesInvoiceDocumentDetailModel",
                "LocalSalesInvoiceDocumentGoodsServiceDetailModel",
                "LocalSalesInvoiceDocumentGoodsDetailModel"
            ],
            "_id": "e4dc3121-9ef7-4eef-ba60-a76a96882269",
            "Type": null,
            "Dsc": "￘ﾳￛﾌ￘ﾨ ￘ﾲ￙ﾅￛﾌ￙ﾆￛﾌ",
            "IsAuto": false,
            "IdGds": 1141601,
>!          "Amount": "1", //I want this field
            "Price": "1520000",//I want and this field
            "DiscountAmount": "0",
            "DiscountPercent": "0",
            "ExtraAmount": "0",
            "ExtraPercent": "0",
            "TaxAmount": "0",
            "IsAutoDiscount": false,
            "IsAutoExtra": false,
            "IdInv": null,
            "IdPrs": null,
            "IdUnt": null
        }
    ],
}
```

I want access amount and price field with my $project in aggregate framework please help me trough it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple `$project` operator, specify `1` for each field you want to keep.

For example :

```
db.SlsIvcDtls.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Amount": 1,
      "Price": 1,
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it on mongoplayground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/aLxBZAAPCr5

By default, `$project`operator will keep the `_id` field. If you want to remove it, you can change the query as follows :

```
db.SlsIvcDtls.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Amount": 1,
      "Price": 1,
      "_id" : 0,
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: sorry my bad I didn't show my document structure accurately SlsIvcDtls is list field in my document

Comment: Please also add the expected answer then. It's not clear anymore what you want as output